# Find the mean and standard deviation of vectors within a list

Tags: r, list

```
data = list(structure(c(0, 1, 3, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 
    7L), .Dimnames = list(c("TRIAL1", "severity"), c("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", 
    "ITEM6", "ITEM7", "ITEM8"))), structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("TRIAL1", "severity"), c("ITEM1", 
    "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", "ITEM6", "ITEM7", "ITEM8"))), structure(c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("TRIAL1", 
    "severity"), c("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", "ITEM6", "ITEM7", "ITEM8"))), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("TRIAL1", 
        "severity"), c("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", "ITEM6", "ITEM7", "ITEM8"))), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("TRIAL1", 
        "severity"), c("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", "ITEM4", "ITEM6", "ITEM7", "ITEM8"))))


[[1]]
         ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM7 ITEM8
TRIAL1       0     3    -1    -1    -3     2     0
severity     1     0     0     0     0     0     0

[[2]]
         ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM7 ITEM8
TRIAL1       0     0     2     0     0     0     0
severity     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

[[3]]
         ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM7 ITEM8
TRIAL1       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
severity     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

[[4]]
         ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM7 ITEM8
TRIAL1       0     0     0     0     0     0     0
severity     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

[[5]]
         ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM6 ITEM7 ITEM8
TRIAL1      99     0     0     0     0     0     0
severity     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation of each `ITEM` for `TRIAL1`. The catch is that I want to treat all the entries with 99 as 0. For instance: for `ITEM1`, the `TRIAL1` values are 0, 0, 0, 0 and 0 (since I want to set 99 = 0). So the mean is 0, and the standard deviation is also 0.

```
sum = Reduce("+",lapply(list, function(x) {x[2,][x[1,]!=0] <- 0; replace(x, which(x==99), 0)}))
mean = sum/length(list)
```

This gives me the means of each `ITEM`. But how can I calculate the standard deviation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option after the initial processing based on the OP's code (i.e. until `replace` 99 with 0), would be to `rbind` the `list` to a `matrix` ('m1'), and then use `colSds` to get the standard deviation for each "ITEM" after subsetting by row names.

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data, function(x) {
       x[2,][x[1,]!=0] <- 0
      replace(x, which(x==99), 0)}))
colSds(m1[c(TRUE, FALSE),])
colSds(m1[c(FALSE, TRUE),])
```

If there are many unique row names, it may be better to `split` by row names and then do the `colSds`

```
t(sapply(split(1:nrow(m1), row.names(m1)),
                    function(i) colSds(m1[i,])))
```

---

Or another option would be to convert the `list` to `data.table`, rbind the `list` using `rbindlist`, group by row names ('rn'), we loop through the "ITEM" columns and get the `sd`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(data, function(x) {
             x[2,][x[1,]!=0] <- 0
             x <- replace(x, which(x==99), 0)
             setDT(as.data.frame(x), keep.rownames=TRUE)}))
dt[, lapply(.SD, sd), by = rn]
     rn     ITEM1    ITEM2    ITEM3     ITEM4    ITEM6     ITEM7 ITEM8
#1:   TRIAL1 0.0000000 1.341641 1.095445 0.4472136 1.341641 0.8944272     0
#2: severity 0.4472136 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000     0
```

If we want both `mean` and `sd` in one call

```
dt[, unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) list(mean(x), 
                sd(x))), recursive=FALSE), by = rn]
```

---

The above method can be replicated in `base R` with `aggregate`

```
d1 <- data.frame(rn = row.names(m1), `row.names<-`(m1, NULL))
aggregate(.~rn, d1, sd)
#        rn     ITEM1    ITEM2    ITEM3     ITEM4    ITEM6     ITEM7 ITEM8
#1 severity 0.4472136 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000     0
#2   TRIAL1 0.0000000 1.341641 1.095445 0.4472136 1.341641 0.8944272     0
```

For both `mean` and `sd`

```
do.call(data.frame,aggregate(.~rn, d1, 
         function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))
```